# How to CSS style a div to look like a GUI control box with a label?

Tags: css

I am really interested in making a PHP page with user input boxes and various other elements to look like the control boxes you see on old school GUIs that had borders beginning and terminating with the box label.

See here:
[image]

How to do that with css?

Comment: Which part was giving you difficulty?

Comment: I can make a div, give it a border, and add a label, but the label is on the inside or the outside

Comment: I'm still not certain what you mean. Can you show your current attempt or cut out the part of the image that actually concerns you? That would clarify things a lot.

Comment: use a [fieldset](http://reference.sitepoint.com/html/fieldset)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't use a div. HTML has `<fieldset>` and `<legend>` which are designed for this usecase and render like that by default.

```
<fieldset>
  <legend>Motor 1 Log</legend>
  <label>Movements <input></label>
  <label>Over-Currents <input></label>
  <label>Amphous <input></label>
</fieldset>
```